# My code doesn't recognize layout-xlarge-land?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a landscape and portrait mode only for tablets. For portrait mode I added the files under layout-xlarge and for landscape in tablets I added files under layout-xlarge-land, but just to test if its working I tried switching the background color under landscape to green, but it didnt seem to work. Is there anything else I need to alter for code to recognize landscape mode for tablets?

Comment: Make sure you don't have `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity in manifest

Comment: I have this in my manifest under the acticities : android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: should i remove it or alter it? I dont want landscape for android phones, jsut tablets, will ti affect that?

Comment: remove the orientation from that and use the folder layout-sw600dp-land that says that only devices with the smallest width at least 600dp in landscapre orientation will load that xml

Comment: that didnt work sadly, do i need to call it specifically from my source file for the layout fragment un der landscape?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `layout-w600dp-land` instead of `layout-xlarge-land`.  The xlarge, large, etc. have been depreciated.  [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) is some more information on all the different combinations that you can use starting with Android 3.2.

**UPDATE**

If you want to set your layout in xml you have to have a xml layout in both layout-w600dp and layout-w600dp-land.  For example `layout-w600dp/my_frag_layout.xml` and `layout-w600dp-land/my_frag_layout.xml`.  In your onCreate method make a call to `setContentView(R.layout.my_frag_layout);`  The system will choose which view is the best fit.

Comment: ok it seems like a weird issue, so for the land I switched the  background color to red and for the portrait i switched the background color to green and seems like whenever i launch the app in the portrait mode the ffragment shows background as green and when i tilt to landscape it remains green, on the other hand when i do the same with landscape, like launch my app in landscape, it shows as red and remains red for portrait, is there a way for it to do this such that no matter what orientation i start it with it remains the green fragment for portrait and red for landscape

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling onCreate when the rotations are happening?  Make sure you are doing something like android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest file.

Comment: I dont think so, for oncreate method for thatfragment I havent defined anything specifically, just using the landscape and portrait, should i create the calls under that?

Comment: this is what i have in oncreate: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colored, container, false);

Comment: as i said, remove orientation from configChanges in manifest or the SO will not do the orientation changes by itself

Comment: You have to call setContentView(R.id.your_layout_name) again if you want it to use the new appropreiate xml file.  This should be in your onCreate method.  The system chooses the best fit every time onCreate is called.

Comment: @Mikel when i remove the configchanges it goes to the launch page upon orientation change so its not fixing the issue

Comment: @DroidT I am unable to set the setcontentview as i havent set an id for my fragment , when i do and try to call it , its asking me for defining setcontent view. this is what i have in my oncreate public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colored, container, false);
  setImageContainerHeight(view);
  setOnClickListeners(view);
  LayoutUtils.showLoading(view, R.id.colored_parent);
  return view;
 }

Comment: I updated my answer.  It looks like you are setting your view programatically but using the xml qualifiers requires the layouts to be in xml.

Comment: issue I am facing is that my oncreate method doesnt recognize setContentView(R.layout.my_frag_layout); but setcontentview(int), what do i need o do for the same to be recognized?

Comment: Make sure you have `import com.yourpackage.R;` and not android version of R.  If you don't have any xml errors then R.layout.my_frag_layout will resolve to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use layout-sw600dp-land

Answer (score 0):

```
layout-xlarge-land  landscape for 10 inch tablets and 10.1
layout-xlarge-port portrait for 10 inch tablets and 10.1
layout-large-land landscape for 7 inch tablets and 7.1
layout-large-port portrait for 7 inch tablets and 7.1
```

good luck :)

Comment: what about 4 inch tablets?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ended up putting the **phone landscape layout** into a **dedicated folder `layout-h480dp-land`** and putting the **tablet landscape layout** into the **"default" folder `layout-land`**.

I came up with this solution based on the following guides: [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes) and [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).